# How to create an action for the button in separate custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nib

How to create an action for the *button* in the *custom view* created from *nib*.
I created an `Outlet`, it got hooked up to the custom `ViewController`, but when I try to have an action, it doesn't work.

Comment: [YOURBUTTON addTarget:self action:@selector(METHODNAME) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    func METHODNAME()
    {
        print("button click")
    }

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to create IBAction from the nib? or it don't allow to connect with view controller?

Comment: Yes @AdiHardik , it doesn't allow me to connect with the controller. This happens only for the action and outlet works fine..

Comment: @BoobalanNatarajan Are you trying to connect from the nib button object or from the right side menu under 'triggered segues ->' 'action'?

Comment: I have a separate view with a button having a separate view controller and I have called the separate view into a view of main view controller using "loadNibNamed". The separate view got loaded at runtime to mainview, but the   action for button placed in separate view doesn't allow me to connect with separate view controller.. @AdiHardik

Answer (score 2):

This is what you can do

Create an outlet of your **VIEW** (the custom view) instead. Then add selector to the button like this

```
self.viewName.buttonName addTarget:self action:@selector(actionName) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

There are other options like passing a block to the view OR using Delegate pattern, but those will be more of a overkill to do such a simple task. This would be way simplier and better when you are working on a separate view in an XIB

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a nib or storyboard file, then you don't even need the outlet to the button. Simply drag from the button to your class and select "Action" instead of "Outlet". It even lets you select which type of Actions you want to receive, such as "TouchUpInside". If you need to do changes to the button, after it has been clicked, you can also do that inside the newly generated method, as it has a sender property, which is your button.

Answer (score 0):

```
yourView.yourButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourFuncName(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

then somewhere declare your func as below :

```
  @objc func yourFuncName(_ sender: UIButton) {
        do something here}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Button action using both addTarget and Closure

    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var imageView: CustomImageView!

        @IBOutlet weak var awesomeView: AwesomeView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

            awesomeView.button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(button1Action(_:)), for:  .touchUpInside)
            awesomeView.button2Pressed = {
                print("Closure button pressed")
            }

        }

        @objc func button1Action(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //           do something here
        }

    }

    //UIView Declaration

    @IBDesignable class AwesomeView: UIView {

        let kCONTENT_XIB_NAME = "AwesomeView"

        @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
        @IBOutlet weak var button1 : UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var button2 :UIButton!

        //create your closure here
        var button2Pressed : (() -> ()) = {}

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)
            initNib()
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            initNib()
        }

        func initNib() {
            let bundle = Bundle(for: AwesomeView.self)
            bundle.loadNibNamed(kCONTENT_XIB_NAME, owner: self, options: nil)
            addSubview(containerView)
            containerView.frame = bounds
            containerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        }

        @IBInspectable var button1Title: String = "" {
            didSet {
                button1.setTitle(button1Title, for: .normal)
            }
        }

        @IBAction func tapOnButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {


        }

        @IBAction func tapOnButton2Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
            button2Pressed()

        }

    }
```